# Page routing not working in ANGULAR JS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement page routing in Angular JS but its not working here.

Here is code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    debugger;
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'EmployeeHome.aspx',
            controller: 'EmpCtrl'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'ContactUs.html',
            controller: 'EmpCtrl'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'About.html',
            controller: 'EmpCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
});

    app.controller('EmpCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
    {
     $scope.message = "Welcome friends.";
    }
```

Here is my UI page
EmployeeHome.aspx-

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
 <header>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i>About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

Comment: did you add ng-app="myApp" in your html tag

Comment: Yes of course I did

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in your javascript console?

Comment: And check the network tab in your console to see if you don't have any file not found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a '/' in all your `href`. So something like this should work :

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i>About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Contact Us</a></li>
```

Comment: Not any one found it's solution?

Comment: @RiteshGupta i don't see any tag `ng-app="myApp"` is this normal ?

Comment: I did not mentioned in above code but its there

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without runnable example, I don't remember if it's required now but I pass the '$routeProvider' and function in like this:

```
angular.module('staffApp').config(['$routeProvider',
     function($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider.
         when('/home', {
               templateUrl: 'EmployeeHome.aspx',
               controller: 'EmpCtrl'
         }).
    ...
```